# QToolbar OS X no hover effect

Tags: macos, qt, qtoolbar

I have spotted a strange behavior of QToolbar on OS X. I have a toolbar with actions, each action has icon:

[image]

That's good. Unfortunately, when mouse pointer is above an action the action is not highlighted:

[image]

Tooltip successfully appears and when I click on the action it's triggered() event is successfully fired.  I use the same actions for both MainMenu and toolbar. Is there a way to enable this hover effect?

Comment: It seems that this [is a QTBUG.](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-26669)

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I notice problems only with hovering QActions inside QToolbar, tooltips work fine.